# How do I apply the CYK algorithm to this CFG?

Tags: algorithm, theory, context-free-grammar, automata

Let CFG G be:

```
S −→ AB|BA|AC|BD|EE
A −→ a
B −→ b
C −→ EB
D −→ EA
E −→ AB|BA|AC|BD|EE
```

How do I use the CYK algorithm to determine if the string `aabbab` is part of the language?

This is the pseudo code I have in my notes:

```
  for i in 1 .. n
     V[i,1] = { A | A -> x[i] }
  for j in 2..n
     for i in 1 .. n-j+1
        {
          V[i,j] = phi
          for k in 1 .. j-1
             V[i,j] = V[i,j] union { A | A -> BC where B in V[i,k]
                                                 and   C in V[i+k,j-k]}
        }
```

But I am not understanding how the answer got to be in an upside down triangular shape.

For example,

```
V[i,j]               i
         1(b)   2(a)   3(a)   4(b)   5(a)

      1  B      A,C    A,C    B      A,C

      2  S,A    B      S,C    S,A
  j
      3  phi    B      B

      4  phi    S,A,C

      5  S,A,C
         ^
         |_ accept
```

Answer (score 0):

The pseudocode[*] describes how to apply the algorithm to create the chart.

The `[i, j]` pair refers to a substring of the input that starts at the `i`th symbol and extends for `j` symbols.  So `[2, 3]` refers to a 3-symbol substring, starting at symbol 2.  If your input is `baaba`, then `[2, 3]` refers to the `aab` in the middle.  (The indexes are 1-based, not 0-based.)

The chart forms a triangle because you can't have a substring that's longer than the input.  If the input is 5 symbols long, then you can have a value in `[1, 5]`, but you can't have `[2, 5]` because that wouldn't refer to a substring anymore.  So each row is one box shorter than the row before it, forming the triangle.

`V[i, j]` refers to a box in the chart.  Each box is the set of non-terminals that may have produced the substring described by `[i, j]`.

The algorithm relies on the grammar being in Chomsky Normal Form.  In CNF, the right side of each production is either one terminal symbol or two non-terminal symbols.  (There's another algorithm that can transform a context-free grammar into CNF.)

Basically, you start with all the 1-symbol substrings of the input.  The first loop in your pseudocode fills out the top row (`j == 1`) of your chart.  It looks at all the productions in the grammar, and, if the right side of a production corresponds to that symbol, then the non-terminal on the left side of that production is added to the set `V[i, 1]`.  (Your example seems to have some bogus entries in the first row.  The `{A, C}` sets should be just `{A}`.)

The algorithm then proceeds through the rest of the rows, looking for all the possible productions that can produce the corresponding substring.  For each possible way to split the current substring into two, it looks for a corresponding production.  This involves combining pairs of non-terminals from certain boxes on previous rows and checking if there are any productions that produce that pair, thus building a set of non-terminals for that box.

If the box in the last row ends up with a set that contains the start symbol, then the input is valid according to the grammar.  Intuitively, it says that the start symbol is a valid production for making the substring that starts at the first symbol and proceeds for the entire length.

[*] It looks like the pseudocode shown in the question contains some transcription errors.  You'll want to consult an authoritative source to get the details right.